# Generic method declaration with List for generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I've been trying to get a generic method with a generic parameter, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the declaration:

```
/**
 * Set items as table rows content
 * 
 * @param rows - table row content
 */
public abstract void setItems(List<?> rows);
```

Here is the Implementation:

```
@Override
public void setItems(List<Dto> bonuses) {
     //code here
}
```

`Dto` is an actual class, but the compiler says that is does not see its parent.

> The method setItems(List) of type Table must override or
>   implement a supertype method

If I'm defining it as separate parameter in generics declaration then the compiler says that my new type hides an already defined class

I can't manage to say to compiler that I want concrete parameter in this implementation.
I've tried changing it to type instead of wildcard, but produces same result. How to get this to work with concrete implementation (`Dto`) ?

Comment: Well, if your base class interface isn't helpful ... is there a specific reason why you don't want to change that? You know, like putting some type parameter "T" on your base class/interface; and later say T is Dto?

Comment: it would also be possible to change the method to something like: `public abstract void setItems(List<? extends Dto> rows);` and the overriden method looks the same, if `Dto` is some base class.

Comment: I don't know what type of List (i.e List<Dto> or List<Dto2>) will implement and those do not have same parent/base class

Comment: They don't share similar getters, and I want to avoid casting and class checking in methods and implementations that will use this method, if possible

Comment: Do it like @Jägermeister said:
`code public abstract class TestClass<T> {
 public abstract void setItems(List<T> rows);
}`

Comment: Is there no other way? I don't want to mess class desciption for one method definition

Comment: take a look in my answer, using generics (here: "T") is the best way if your objects do not have the same parent/base class

Comment: They have, but the point is that this should somehow work. I only don't know how. Also, this is work-around for already implemented stuff (by oracle/Sun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like @Jägermeister in the comments said:

```
public abstract class TestClass<T> {
    public abstract void setItems(List<T> rows);
}
```

Use:

```
public class Test extends TestClass<Dto> {

    @Override
    public void setItems(List<Dto> rows) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Or you can define your method as

```
public abstract void setItems(List rows);
```

and use like

```
public void setItems(List rows) {....
```

but that is no good way!

Comment: second way would not do, since I would need type-cast, check and who know what else.

Comment: first way is a workaround. Sun clearly uses stuff like that in documention: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html , but I can't figure out what's missing in method implementing.

Comment: in your method you use code`<?>` which is not a parent class from your code`Dto` so the compiler throws the error. another alternative is to use code`<Object>` so every class can be used. But you can not limit it to code`Dto` without reflection

Comment: Sun/Oracle uses reflection for this. You can take a look in the list interface: code`public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>` and so on. Your link says you should use reflections like the first way.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what you mean. They are not using code`<?>`, they are demonstrating how it will not work in that code! Look at the comment in line 3:`code c.add(o); // compile-time error`

Comment: Unless I specify the class for generic at Class level, there's no way to narrow generic without breaking contract with it's parent. Since stuff is like this, will accept this answer as "answer", because this is the way to do it. It's unfortunate that I can't do that, but I guess it would allow for really crazy shenanigans.